# Neo4j how to get the common node between two nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am building a graph database for a given family and I want to get
the common family member(node) between two family members(two nodes).

I should say that the two nodes are not directly connected to the common requested node.

```
MATCH (b:Person)-[:RELATES*]->(a:Person)<-[:RELATES*]-(c:Person)
where ID(b) = 7 
and ID(c) = 50
RETURN a
```

a -> b -> c

d -> c

What I'm expecting when I run the query with 'a' and 'd' is to get 'c'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way.

Another way is to get all ancestor nodes from each, and then intersect the two lists:

```
MATCH (b:Person), (c:Person)
where ID(b) = 7 
and ID(c) = 50
WITH [(b)-[:RELATES*]->(ancestor) | ancestor] as bAncestors, [(c)-[:RELATES*]->(ancestor) | ancestor] as cAncestors
RETURN apoc.coll.intersection(bAncestors, cAncestors) as commonAncestors
```

This uses APOC Procedures for the intersection() function, but you can use this pure Cypher workaround instead if you don't have APOC:

```
...
RETURN [ancestor in bAncestors WHERE ancestor in cAncestors] as commonAncestors
```

Comment: I wish a can thank you enough, It works after waisting two days trying to solve it.
Real thanks to you.

Comment: Do you know if spring data JPA can do the same thing without writing custom queries ?